# IE11 select element not displaying options properly

Tags: html

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yb4p1mz8/)

In IE11, if you make a simple drop-down list such as the following,

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
</select>
```

It doesn't display properly.

[image]

For some reason, the selected element stays at the header and forces everything else above it. Is this a bug? How do I get the select dropdowns to work properly in IE?

Comment: It's by design for almost all modern browsers. You can see similar behavior in Chrome. Apologies if I misunderstood your problem completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a bug, that is just the way that IE 11 styles their dropdown box. One way of to get all of your dropdowns to have cross-browser compatibility is to design your own option; or better yet use a plug-in. For example, [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).

EDIT: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18689790/4607022).